# Image button isn't properly visible when playing

Tags: android

In android studio I´ve added a ButtonView in aRelative layout.Although in the previsualization it is ok, it doesn't appear when playing.

code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.xxx"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    </WebView>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_gear" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Tip (*common misuse of `mipmap`s*): Please note that `mipmap` folders are meant to hold the **launcher icon ONLY**.

Comment: Then, where should I place my gear image, in any separate folder or in one with a specific name?

Comment: In one with a specific name: `drawable` (drawable-xyzdpi, actually)

Comment: Ok, thanks:) additionally, apart from being more hygienic this way, does the other way lead to errors?

Comment: I don't know. Many do so (it's a *common mistake*). I prefer to follow the rules.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_below="@+id/webV"` in your`ImageButton`

```
   <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/webV"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_gear" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty strange but if you use **android:background** instead of **app:srcCompat**, it may work

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@mipmap/ic_gear" />
```